# How can I rewrite a class component using state to a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently developing an application using React Native.

I have a class component using state and want to rewrite it to a function component for working the same content as the previous class component.

But I can't rewrite it...of course, the original code(class component) works well

This trial app has a component that has a TextInput and two buttons (ADD and DELETE).

When I press the ADD Button, a new component appears. If I press the DELETE Button that the same component disappears.

I control the TextInput with the index which is the same number as the index of the component.

---

What I can't resolve is inputting some text in the input area.

When I input some text, I can input only a couple of texts and the input area view doesn't reflect collect value...

How can I resolve this problem when I rewrite the code to function one?

---

Here is the original code (class component):

```
    import React from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
    
    function Item({ text, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <Text>{index}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
            value={text}
            onChangeText={(t) => {
              handleInput(index, t);
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="ADD"
            onPress={() => {
              handleAdd();
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="DELETE"
            onPress={() => {
              handleDelete(index);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    class RewriteClass extends React.Component {
      state = {
        texts: [""],
      };
    
      handleAdd = () => {
        const { texts } = this.state;
        this.setState({ texts: [...texts, ""] });
      };
    
      handleDelete = (index) => {
        const texts = [...this.state.texts];
        texts.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ texts: texts });
      };
    
      handleInput = (index, text) => {
        const { texts } = this.state;
        texts[index] = text;
        this.setState({ texts });
      };
    
      render() {
        const { texts } = this.state;
    
        return (
          <View>
            {texts.map((text, i) => (
              <Item
                key={"" + i}
                text={text}
                handleInput={this.handleInput}
                handleAdd={this.handleAdd}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                index={i}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      list: {
        backgroundColor: "#ddd",
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,
      },
    });
    
    export default RewriteClass;
```

Here is the code I tried rewriting so far  (function component):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

function Item({ text, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(t) => {
          handleInput(index, t);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function RewriteFunction() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([""]);

  //handleAdd = () => {
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setTexts((v) => {
      const ret = [...v, ""];
      return ret;
    });
  };

  //handleDelete = (index) => {
  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    setTexts((v) => {
      const ret = [...v];
      ret.splice(index, 1);
      return ret;
    });
  };

  //handleInput = (index, text) => {
  const handleInput = (index, text) => {
    setTexts((v) => {
      const ret = v;
      ret[index] = text;
      return ret;
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {texts.map((text, i) => (
        <Item
          key={"" + i}
          text={text}
          handleInput={handleInput}
          handleAdd={handleAdd}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

---

node : 12.18.3

react native : 4.10.1

expo : 3.22.3

---

Comment: You should use a linter. You can't use the class way of defining properties in functions. `handleInput` should be lead with a `const handleInput = ... `

Comment: @Julian, I changed the code following your advice, but I still have the same problem...

Comment: Can you update your code with the latest changes and add the current error message?

Comment: @Julian, I updated the code, I don't have any error message so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the child component wasn't updating. We would have to allocate dedicated state for it, which just initializes with the value coming from the props:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

export function Item({ text, handleInput, handleAdd, handleDelete, index }) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(text);

  return (
    <View style={styles.list}>
      <Text>{index}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        value={inputValue}
        onChangeText={(t) => {
          setInputValue(t);
          handleInput(index, t);
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="ADD"
        onPress={() => {
          handleAdd();
        }}
      />
      <Button
        title="DELETE"
        onPress={() => {
          handleDelete(index);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default function RewriteFunction() {
  const [texts, setTexts] = useState([""]);

  //handleAdd = () => {
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setTexts((v) => {
      const ret = [...v, ""];
      return ret;
    });
  };

  //handleDelete = (index) => {
  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    setTexts((v) => {
      const ret = [...v];
      ret.splice(index, 1);
      return ret;
    });
  };

  //handleInput = (index, text) => {
  const handleInput = (index, text) => {
    let t = texts;
    t[index] = text;
    setTexts(t);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {texts.map((text, i) => (
        <Item
          key={text + i.toString()}
          text={texts[i]}
          handleInput={handleInput}
          handleAdd={handleAdd}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
          index={i}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  list: {
    backgroundColor: "#ddd",
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, in case of this code, when I delete some component with DELETE button, the rest component shows the wrong value...so I shouldn't rewrite like this code.

Comment: I updated my answer. The issue was the child component wasn't updating. We would have to allocate dedicated state for it, which just initializes with the value coming from the props:

Comment: this time the code works as I expect! thank you so much for your support !!